# The set of values of $c$ for which the angle between the vectors $cxi-6j+3k$ & $xi-2j+cxk$ is acute for every x belongs to R ????

Tags: vectors

How do we find the set of values of $c$ for which the angle between the vectors $cx\hat{i}-6\hat{j}+3\hat{k}$  &  $x\hat{i}-2\hat{j}+cx\hat{k}$ is acute for every $x$ belongs to $\mathbb{R}$ ????

I tried to apply $\cos\theta$ formula but not getting the correct answer. Please give proper and full explanation.

Comment: "I tried to apply cos theta formula" Excellent, so please show the details of your computations when you tried to apply this formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For two vectors to be acute, the inner product has to be positive.

$$\langle (cx,-6,3),(x,-2,cx) \rangle>0$$
which is equivalent to 
$$cx^2+12+3cx>0$$

Rearranging the terms:

$$cx^2+3cx+12>0$$

For this condition to hold, we require $c\geq0$ otherwise the quadratic function is strictly concave and will attain and some negative value. Also, we require the discriminant $(3c)^2-48c=9c^2-48c$ to be negative.

Credit: Thanks for JimmyK4542 for catching my mistake in the sign of the discriminant.

Comment: Don't we need the discriminant to be negative to guarantee that there are no zeros?

Comment: Yikes, thanks for catching that...

Answer (score 3):

The angle between two vectors $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ is acute if and only if $\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v} > 0$.

So, the angle between $\vec{u} = cx\hat{i}-6\hat{j}+3\hat{k}$ and $\vec{v} = x\hat{i}-2\hat{j}+cx\hat{k}$ is acute iff $\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v} = (cx)(x)+(-6)(-2)+(3)(cx) = cx^2+3cx+12 > 0$.

For the quadratic $cx^2+3cx+12$ to be positive for all real $x$, we need either the leading coefficient $c$ to be positive and the discriminant of the quadratic to be negative (i.e. the graph of the quadratic is concave up and there are no zeros) or for $c = 0$ (in this case, $cx^2+3cx+12 = 12$ which is always positive). Can you calculate the discriminant and figure out what values of $c > 0$ make the discriminant negative?

EDIT: Thanks to Siong Thye Goh for catching the fact that $c \ge 0$.

Comment: I made a mistake just now, it's ok for $c$ to be $0$. I think the concave should be convex.

Comment: ^Yes, $c = 0$ also works. Also, "concave up" and "convex" mean the same thing.